# will a call to SQL cause my multi threading app to bottleneck?

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

will the call to SQL in my multi threaded application cause the app to be bottleneck?

Is the logic i am using valid and conform to best practice?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8000);
        TcpClient client;
        listener.Start();

        while (true) // Add your exit flag here
        {
            client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ThreadProc, client);
        }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }//Main


    private static void ThreadProc(object obj)
    {
        var client = (TcpClient)obj;
        // Do your work here...

        NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(ns))
        {
           writer.WriteLine("220 SMTP server ready.");
           writer.Flush();

           using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ns))
           {
              //parse + persist smtp message here...
              //save email message parts to a Email table in SQL SVR(from, to, body...)
           }
        }
    }//ThreadProc
```

Comment: One thread per client doesn't tend to scale well, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505567/new-thread-per-client-connection-in-socket-server

Comment: @damien: i am using connection pooling, not a new thread for each connection. Also a side note... This code handles 20,000 emails with out a sweat- cpu @ 65% max

Comment: What do you mean by app to be bottleneck?  Adding a call to the database is going to create a bottleneck in the processing.  Whether or not it's an important one will depend on the load, specs of the machine and other bottlenecks in the system.  It may be that reading the entire e-mail message from the streamreader is a more significant bottleneck in your processing.  To an extent, you have to suck it and see after you've written the code.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach this is to have a Queue which you add the stuff you're going to parse and persist and then have that serviced by a pool of threads, or even just one thread, it depends on the expected throughput. The key here is the queue is serviced as soon as possible, but if there is a backlog it doesn't affect adding more items.

Edit:

There are a bunch of unknowns in your scenario, so my solution was equally vague, but I should of explained that.

The problem with your problem is I don't know how long your sql will run, or what action should be taken if it fails/times out, or how many of these sql statements you're expecting to queue up or run.

My solution would be to first extract the public facing interface for a) queuing an operation and b) processing an operation. this gives you the opportunity to, at a later date, or even now, switch out the queuing mechanism for something more appropriate.

So, take the case where by you are queuing work items, and the database stops responding. Suddenly nothing is being saved. Does that affect what your application does? Is there any sort of transactional issue here? Would it be better perhaps to be writing the work item to something like MSMQ? SQL Server also has a broker service which could be pretty spot on for what you want.

So I'm not going to add any code, but think in these terms:

1) Specify interfaces interface:

public interface QueueWorkItem
{
    void AddWorkItemToQueue(WorkItem item);
}

public interface ConsumeWorkItem
{
    bool ItemsInQueue {get;}
    WorkItem GetNextItem();
}

You don't have to use these, it's just examples.

2) Build a class that implements the interfaces
This is the fun bit, you have to worry about threading and blocking (Look for producer consumer pattern) You could always use the threadpool and have the ConsumeWorkItem do nothing really.

Finally, lets talk about the threadpool. It's fine, but you don't have much control over it, and there's no guarantee that all the threads running in it are yours.

Hope that helps.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx leads me to believe that ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ThreadProc, client);
uses a queue. am i missing something here?

Comment: Oh hi, sorry I forgot to comment back on this. I'll add an edit to flesh out what I mean.